# keyVaultClient - get a secret

Tags: azure, azure-functions, access-token, azure-keyvault

I am using Azure function to do an action, in this action I need to get a secret from a keyvault.
I am using this code in order to get the secret

```
 var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
 var keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient((authority, resource, scope) => azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(resource));

var secret= await keyVaultClient.GetSecretAsync($"https://{KeyVaultName}.vault.azure.net/", "SecretName");
```

When I run it locally it's work but when I run the function in azure I am getting an error "Forbidden"
How can I get the secret from a keyVault inside my azure function?

Thanks!

Comment: Your App needs permissions to access the KeyVault. RTM. https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions

Comment: PS: [According to doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/service-to-service-authentication) you should not use `AzureServiceTokenProvider`, [see this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/overview/azure/app-auth-migration) for alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forbidden might indicate that the identity assumed by the Azure Function does not have access rights over the specific Azure Key Vault.

From the Azure Portal or via CLI/API, head into the relevant Azure Key Vault resource -> Access Policies -> Add Access Policy -> Assign the Azure Function identity with the following permissions:

- Secret List
- Secret Get

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the KeyVault client inside your Function, you can have it much more simple if you can use KeyVault-referenced AppSettings (depends a bit of course on your scenario if thats an option). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references

Then you can simple use the secret like any setting and read it as an Env variable.